# uint64 does not name a type

Tags: c++

The compiler displays this message  'uint64 does not name a type' every time I try to execute using uint64, and same goes for uint or unit32, I have imported stdint.h but was useless. the other question is when I execute using int, I get different value for the variable z, less value like -160000 then -140000 and so on with every subsequent execution. how to solve that? here is the code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <fstream>
using std::ifstream;

#include <cstring>

/* Returns the amount of milliseconds elapsed since the UNIX epoch. Works on both
 * windows and linux. */

uint64 GetTimeMs64()
{
    FILETIME ft;
    LARGE_INTEGER li;

    /* Get the amount of 100 nano seconds intervals elapsed since January 1, 1601 (UTC) and copy it
     * to a LARGE_INTEGER structure. */
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
    li.LowPart = ft.dwLowDateTime;
    li.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;

    uint64 ret;
    ret = li.QuadPart;
    ret -= 116444736000000000LL; /* Convert from file time to UNIX epoch time. */
    ret /= 10000; /* From 100 nano seconds (10^-7) to 1 millisecond (10^-3) intervals */

    return ret;
}

const int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 512;
const int MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE = 20;
const char* const DELIMITER = "|";

int main()
{
    // create a file-reading object
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("promotion.txt"); // open a file
    if (!fin.good()) 
        return 1; // exit if file not found

    // read each line of the file
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        // read an entire line into memory
        char buf[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE];
        fin.getline(buf, MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE);

        // parse the line into blank-delimited tokens
        int n = 0; // a for-loop index

        // array to store memory addresses of the tokens in buf
        const char* token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {}; // initialize to 0

        // parse the line
        token[0] = strtok(buf, DELIMITER); // first token
        if (token[0]) // zero if line is blank
        {
            for (n = 1; n < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; n++)
            {
                token[n] = strtok(0, DELIMITER); // subsequent tokens
                if (!token[n]) break; // no more tokens
            }
        }

        // process (print) the tokens
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n = #of tokens
            cout << "Token[" << i << "] = " << token[i] << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    uint64 z = GetTimeMs64();
    cout << z << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: did you install 64 bit compilers? what version of windows and what version of compilers do you have installed?

Comment: does `uint64_t` name a type? .. or `uint16_t` or `uint32_t` for that matter..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type is named `uint64_t`. Same goes for `uint32_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint8_t`, etc.

`uint` doesn't exist. You might have intended simply `unsigned int`.

Comment: uint64_t worked well and the result of z is consistent, thanks
here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64.aspx
uiny64 is mentioned as 64-bit unsigned integer.